# Using "Reset PC" from an image install, will any image-specific content remain?

Tags: windows-10, images

***Windows 10***

I have a laptop with windows installed from a system image. If I use the "Reset this PC" option from settings, will I be guaranteed a vanilla Windows 10 install, or is it possible anything non-vanilla from the image could be retained?

More generally, if I have 2 computers of identical hardware that have windows 10 installed from 2 different system images with potentially different various software included in each image, and I choose "Reset this PC," will they both have identical hard drive contents afterword (assume I have selected "remove everything" when doing the reset)?

Comment: That is [correct](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/push-button-reset-overview) and the only thing that would be kept are system drivers, which are backed up to the Component Store [`%WinDir%\WinSxS`] as of v1809.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I use the "Reset this PC" option from settings, will I be
> guaranteed a vanilla Windows 10 install, or is it possible anything
> non-vanilla from the image could be retained?

If the laptop has the original recovery partition still intact, then Reset to factory specifications will reset it entirely and not carry anything over from the prior image.

It is a good way to start fresh.

The same is true for the other computer, again assuming that the original recovery partition is intact.

If you need to, you can usually get the Recovery USB Key from the laptop manufacturer. That will also let you rebuild fresh.